# how can I disable all tableviewcells' interactions but enable headerviews' interactions in uitableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

The situation is:

I want to disable uitableview cells' click action when my table is loading data.

So during the loading time, I used:

`self.tableview.allowsSelection = NO;`

or

`self.tableview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

to disable actions.

But I finally found I just want to disable cellviews' interaction, but enable headerview's interaction.

Is there any convenient way to do that?

Thanks a lot.

additions:

My cells were already on screen. And I'm going to fetch some new data from server. So the old cells is outdated. That's why I want to disable them.

MORE CODES TO MY QUESTION:

FOR tableview's header view, it contains a segmentControl:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    headerView addSubview:self.segmentControl;
    ...
    return headerView;
}
```

For segmentControl's Action, it has an action for `forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged` :

```
[_segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And for when value changing:

```
-(void)segmentValueChanged{
    //tag 1
    [self.somedata loadFromServer];
}
```

loadFromServer is an Asynchronous method, means we don't need to wait for it, we can do other things now.and When this method is finished, it will call delegate's function: `mentionDataLoadFinished`

```
-(void)mentionDataLoadFinished{
    //tag 2
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

I want to disable all cells interaction during tag 1 to tag 2, but I still want my headerview works normally.

Comment: made an edit to my answer @youKnowDai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a subclass of `UITableViewCell` using a single static variable to change the state of all of the cells at once. Although, this will affect all of the cells in your entire app, regardless of the state of your current view controller. If there are two tables on screen using the same cell subclass, for instance, all cells will be enabled once the first `UITableView` finishes loading.

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
+ (void)allowInteraction:(BOOL)allow;
@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell
static BOOL __allowInteraction = NO;
+ (void)allowInteraction:(BOOL)allow {
  __allowInteraction = allow;
}
- (BOOL)userInteractionEnabled {
  return __allowInteraction;
}
@end
```

**Edit**: The subclass `UITableViewCell` will accomplish this for you, or you could set a flag and call `reloadData`. It will only reload the cells that are on screen, so it will be quick.

```
- (void)refreshFromServer {
  disableCells = YES;
  [self.tableView reloadData];

  [self anAsynchronousProcessWithACompletionHandler:^{
    disableCells = NO;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
  }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
  // ..
  cell.userInteractionEnabled = !disableCells;
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: my cells are alreay on screen. So disabling them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` maybe need too much time. And i want to know if iterating cells also need a lot of time.Thanks

Comment: This is confusing to me. If your cells are already on screen, you are no longer loading table data. Please clarify what you mean in your original question.

Comment: sorry, I didn't make it clearly. Im going to synchronize local data with server. The cells alreay on screen is outdated. So I want to disable them, and loading the newest data from server. During the loading time, I still want to enable click action for the headerview. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath', you can set cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO, this should do the trick.

--EDIT--
Make 2 booleans in your .h file loadStarted and loadingInProgress, by default these booleans are set to 'NO'

now once you make a request to your webApp, you can set these booleans to 'YES'

```
loadStarted = YES;
loadingInProgress = YES;
```

in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
//Check if those 2 booleans are equal to YES
if(loadStarted && loadingInProgress){

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}else{

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
```

The above code will make sure that your cells are disabled when the loading is done.
Now you will have to make sure that you reload the tableview twice, once when you make a request and the other when you get something back.

Also when you receive data back from your server, you will set both booleans to 'NO', this should take care of it

**Hope this helps**

Comment: `userInteractionEnabled` does not need tableview to call reloadData method. But if I set cell.userInteractionEnabled in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I have to call reloadData to disable the interaction. Is that true?

Comment: I don't believe you would need to call reloadData. 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' is called by the compiler when it wants to change something in the UITableViewCell or if it is trying to create a new UITableViewCell, did you try setting cell.userInteractioEnabled to 'NO' and check if that is the behavior you wanted it to have?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called by the *compiler*. Also, it will not be called for cells already on screen when the state changes.

Comment: I meant if we want to make a UITableViewCell update its contents

Comment: @youKnowDai, so are you making a web request to populate your cells?

Comment: @Shabarinath Pabba, Yeah, That's what I want to do.